# Algorithm to find who wins in traversal game

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, graph, geography

We will be working with graphs, and two players. In this connected graph, the winning condition is that the second player has no other paths to take. The catch is that once a path is taken by a player, it can't be taken again.

Let us assume the initial input is adjacency list (x,y) means x has path to y

The goal is to return a set of vertices that player 1 can choose such that it will always win.

For example, if I have `[(1,2), (2,0), (0, 3), (3,2)]` and player 1 starts, then we should return `[1, 0, 3]`.  We cannot return `2`:

2 --> player 1 starts here

(2,0) --> player 2 goes to 0

(0,3) --> player 1 goes to 3

(3,2) --> player 2 goes to 2

(2,0) --> player 1 cannot go here, already taken

```
already_visited = []

turn = 1

result = []

def findStarting(L):
    global already_visited
    global turn
    global result

    for x,y in L:
        allowed = can_visit(L, y) # function tell me which I can visit safely

        turn = (turn % 2) + 1 # increment the turn

        already_visited.append((x,y)) # we visited this edge

        res = findStarting([(x, y)]) # recursive call (search on this node for paths)


    if (turn == 2): return True

def can_visit(L, y): 
    res = []
    for a,b in L: if (a==y and (a,b) not in already_visited): res.append((a,b))
    return res
```

I am having trouble with the recursive case. I think what I want to do is return `True` if we reach a point where turn is 2 and the player has no paths they can take, but I am not sure how to move ahead from here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple recursive solution.  It is not efficient, it's brute force search without any caching of intermediate states, so it can definitely be made faster, though I don't know if there is an efficient (i.e. non-exponential) solution to this problem.

```
def firstPlayerWins(g,v):
  for i,e in enumerate(g):
    if e[0]==v and not firstPlayerWins(g[:i]+g[i+1:],e[1]):
        return True
  return False

def winningVertices(g):
  return [v for v in set(e[0] for e in g) if firstPlayerWins(g,v)]

winningVertices([(1,2), (2,0), (0, 3), (3,2)])
## [0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. For example `winningVertices([(0,1),(1,2)])` should return `[1,2]` but only returns `[1]`

Comment: 2 is not winning in that case.  Starting at 2, the first player has no moves available and loses.

Comment: We assume that the first player initially "moves to" `2`. Hence after they are at their first vertex, the opponent moves. In this sense technically all nodes that have no connections outwards are valid candidates

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the initial insturctions wrong. Actually the example above (the original example in my question) should be returning `[0,1,3]` (not 2)

Comment: In that case, it's just the opposite, since in effect player 2 goes first after player 1 chooses the starting vertex.  In your example, the correct answer is actually just `[1]`, and `[0,2,3]` are the vertices where the second player wins.  Basically, just rename the function to `losingVertices` instead of `winningVertices`.